# Weird behavior from Row_number interaction with Case When in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to create a table that lists to me the most recent price and the second most recent price for each product in a certain range of quantity (meaning, if I buy 100+ products, I will have a better price than buying 50-99). The table does not contain any row with empty prices. The data comes from 2 different systems but follow the same format on them. The table has the following format:

| Product | Price | Range | Valid_from | Valid_until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 100 | 01/01/2023 | 21/03/2023 |
| b | 2 | 100 | 01/01/2023 | 22/03/2023 |
| a | 1.5 | 50 | 01/01/2023 | 22/03/2023 |
| a | 0.8 | 100 | 01/12/2022 | 31/12/2023 |

The idea is that in the end I have a table like this:

| Product | Old Price | New Price | Range | New Price Valid From | New Price Valid Until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0.8 | 1 | 100 | 01/01/2023 | 21/03/2023 |
| a | Null | 1.5 | 50 | 01/01/2023 | 22/03/2023 |
| b | Null | 2 | 100 | 01/12/2022 | 31/12/2023 |

I am using this query to try to generate it:

```sql
WITH ranked_price as(
SELECT 
range, 
range_price, 
valid_from, 
valid_until,  
product,
row_number() over (partition by product, range order by valid_from desc) as rwn
FROM product_table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
range, 
range_price, 
valid_from, 
valid_until,  
product,
row_number() over (partition by product, range order by valid_from desc) as rwn
FROM product_table2)


SELECT 
product,
range,
max(case when rwn = 1 then range_price end) new_price,
max(case when rwn = 2 then range_price end) old_price,
max(valid_from) valid_from,
max(valid_until) valid_until
FROM ranked_price group by product, range
```

However, I am getting several rows with a Null new_price while having a non-Null old_price, which should not be possible. For this cases, the behavior is very weird, since when I remove the second part of the query and check the RWN values, it shows that, for that product, all values are 1, but once I add the second part, some of the rows get a RWN = 2 while previously it was a 1.

[image]

Is this a bug of the language or am I messing something up here?
If so, what can I do to make it correct?

Comment: Why is your example pulling from two different tables (`product_table1` and `product_table2`) ?  Why does product `a` in your sample data have three rows with overlapping date ranges? What you grouping by to reduce the original 4 rows to 3? Why would the `old_price` for `a` in the second row be NULL when that price isn't the oldest one? Please review the validity of your data and clarify how you plan to collapse teh rows. Only then can we advise on how to write your windowing function.

Comment: Hello, I edited the question with some more details. I hope it clarifies these points for you.

Comment: you still have two `a` records with range `100` that have overlapping dates, and we still don't know what `product_table1` vs. `product_table2` is.